# Get kendomenu events in C# code behind

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

Hello I'm new in using kendo components.
I have a basic question, maybe too elementary to appear in the archive.
How do I get from C# code behind an event from kendo components in Visual Studio project?
e.g. the equivalent of onClick event of a normal Button1 to trigger the Button1_onClick() method in C# code behind?
Thank you very much
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kendo widgets won't send any event to your code behind.

You can handle the events it sends through javascript, and use them to submit forms or make ajax requests

You could do something like:

```
$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    select: onSelect
});
function onSelect(e){
   var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
   // Make an axaj call to a handler that updates the value with dataItem.value 
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that KendoUI is nothing but an extension of regular elements you use in your html forms.